# Please stratify salaries by industry in the Salary Calculator

Tags: feature-request, salary-calculator

Here in the UK (but I strongly suspect the same is true elsewhere), there’s vast variation in salaries across industries. The numbers produced at the moment are therefore not very helpful as a reference point for salary negotiations.

As an example, I suspect that the high salaries in my location are strongly skewed by the financial tech sector. Unfortunately that’s simply irrelevant in my industry (biotech), which pays a lot lower salaries on average.

I would like for the salary calculator to let us specify what industry we are in.

Comment: it all comes to volume though... we'd need a significant number of people working in biotech to answer the survey to be able to extract meaningful results from it.

Comment: @g3rv4 Yes, sure. But that’s what statistics and confidence intervals are for. At the very least you’d get a correct answer, rather than a nice-looking but misleading one. At the moment the salary calculator feels very much like toy, rather than like a tool.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I looked at using industry as one of the predictors in the salary calculator, and it was not a good predictor across geographical regions and experience levels, so unfortunately we did not build this feature into the product. I can see that it would make a big difference in certain cases but for our general model/product, it wasn't a significant or important enough predictor.

Comment: OK, somebody please explain to me: how is this question “Unclear what you’re asking”?! What I’m asking is literally *in the title*.

Comment: // , @TylerH, like Konrad already said, that's what statistics and confidence intervals are for. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=confidence+intervals

Comment: @NathanBasanese If you're into data science you may know these terms and how they apply, otherwise you likely don't. To non-scientists, going from 90 to 95% confidence doesn't seem like a huge jump but those who are familiar with what that means understand it is twice as confident. It's not really worth it for the devs to make this change if they have to accompany it with an asterisk that says "we only have 5% confidence in these numbers". The vast majority of people are going to say "okay that's basically no confidence, what's even the point"

Comment: @TylerH I’m *so* curious: why did you change the apostrophes when editing the question?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Probably because the "straight" apostrophes are commonly used by programmers. I have a automated cleanup [userscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/Magic%E2%84%A2Editor.user.js) that replaces those as well.

Comment: @Cerbrus Honestly I’m tempted to file an issue request on that script against this disimprovement. And the only reason I don’t submit a PR is because I don’t see the point of this script over manual editing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Please keep in mind that that is _your opinion_. I think the straight quotes are easier to read. That userscript has proven it's value to me time after time, when editing posts.

Comment: @Cerbrus It’s the opinion of professional typographers and the Unicode consortium, too. It’s also pretty immaterial, it’s clearly a gratuitous change. I don’t go around changing peoples’ straight quotes into curly ones, or ticks into typographically correct apostrophes. Fix mistakes, not personal preferences (*especially* if those go against the professional majority).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'm just explaining why I _think_ the quotes were changed: Probably a side-effect of a automated script. If you don't like it, just change it back. No point in making a big deal about something this insignificant.